# Remove value from array In PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
$array=[1,4,15,8,3,7,15];
```

I get values from DB, so I want to remove "8" value from this array  but **arrays has undefined index**. How can I do this ?

Comment: With [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) and [`unset`](http://php.net/unset) .

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) might be what you're looking for...

Comment: Do you want to remove all "8" if there is many or just one of them?

Comment: Thanks dudes, i must be learn too...

Comment: As @Sergio asked and inferred, be careful you look at all the answers provided on the duplicate answer link. If it is possible that "8" occurs more than once (like "15" in your example) then you'll want to consider something other than the accepted answer.