# How to unset an array element matching index in php?

Tags: php, arrays

$menu contains:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [menu] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Home
                        [controller] => frontends
                        [action] => index
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [menu] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Feedback
                        [controller] => feedbacks
                        [action] => add
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [menu] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Reseller
                        [controller] => resellers
                        [action] => login
                    )

            )

    )
```

I want to delete

```
[2] => Array
        (
            [menu] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Reseller
                    [controller] => resellers
                    [action] => login
                )

        )

unset($menu[2])
```

Works fine. But I am not sure that this menu always under 2 index. So I want to delete this item when `$menu[$i][menu][name] == 'Reseller'`. Anyone able to help?

Comment: If only there was a way to go through the array, check if a condition is true and use that index to remove items. Hint.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Wait, I think thare is a way to go through the array, check if a condition is true and use that index to remove items. Now what is it Ermmmm. Forsomethingorother!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove value from array In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252880/remove-value-from-array-in-php)

Comment: What type of variable is $menu, because with a post/get you just unset it when passing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not test this, but this should work.

```
foreach ($menu as $index => $menu_item) {
    if ($menu_item['menu']['name'] == 'Reseller') {
        unset($menu[$index]);
    }
}
```